# How to add multiple ip address in destination ip in acl rule

Tags: cisco, routing, switching, acl

Iam trying to block a certain host from sending any message to any host in the network
is there is a way to do that or i have to deny host by host ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`deny ip 10.10.10.10/32 255.255.255.255/32` should do it for e.g. `10.10.10.10` as source.

If you want to filter multiple source IPs you need multiple ACL entries unless you can fit a mask to all sources.

For instance, `deny ip 10.10.10.8/30 255.255.255.255/32` filters all broadcasts from hosts `10.10.10.8` through `10.10.10.11`.

Note that wildcard masks needn't be contiguous like subnet masks. You could use `deny ip 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.251 255.255.255.255/32` for sources `10.10.10.10` and `10.10.10.14`.

Answer (score 3):

```
ip access-list acl-01
Deny ip <destination IP> <destination wild card> host <source ip>
permit any any
```

Implementation should be done in interface and direction should be in/out but we cannot tell it exactly without seeing diagram.

```
ip access-group acl-01 in
```

Answer (score 0):

If you even want to block the host from talking to hosts in the same IP-network you have to put a firewall on the host. Another way would be Private Vlan to isolate it and force every communication to go through the next hop (which could be a firewall).

Comment: this is not an answer for question